# Find speed between 2 coordinates in nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgis

I have two coordinates and i want to calculate,what is the user's speed between this points.I am doing on nodejs. I am using these modules:

```
const turf = require('@turf/turf');
const WKT = require('terraformer-wkt-parser')
```

First i have converted these coordinate into line and finally got length of line:

```
    let t_line = turf.lineString([coordinate_first, coordinate_seconde], {
        name: 'line 1'
    });
    let length = turf.length(t_line, {
        units: 'meters'
    });
```

The length is `26.21551736669138`.

The date point created is :

first coordinate : `"2018-08-16T06:35:14.669Z"`

second coordinate : `"2018-08-16T06:35:14.532Z"`

Now this is the difference between these times:

```
var tim = new Date(seconde).getTime();
var newd = new Date(firs).getTime();
```

and : tim - newd = `137`

I am using this formula:

```
    //v = speed
    // s = distance
    // t = time
    // v = s ÷ t
```

`var v = length / (tim - newd)`. This answer is : `0.1913541413627108`.
Is This result millisecond per meter? This is right?

If i want to convert speed to meter per second, i have to divide result into 1000?Then my result is `191.3541413627108 meter per second`. is the result is true?

And if i want to find speed `kilometer per hours`, what can i do?

Comment: Your result is correct. 0.19m/miliSecond == 0.19*1000m/sec

Comment: And 0.19 m/s == 0.19 /3600000 km/h ? Then my result is `5.315392815630856e-5` that is mean, user's speed is almost 5 kilometer per hours @Helpinghand

Comment: It is 191.3m/sec , not 0.19m/s.

Comment: m/s to km/hr conversion is 191m/sec = (191*(18/5))km/hr

Comment: According your guild i write this formula : `var v = (length / (tim - newd) * 1000) * 18 / 5`  correct ? my result is  `688.8749089057589 km/h` @Helpinghand

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I meant.

Comment: Thanks dude @Helpinghand